# Elastic Beanstalk dependencies not available in npm install?

Tags: node.js, sass, gruntjs, gulp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have read [EB Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) to understand how i can set external dependencies for my app. My app is to be installed in a nodejs container which automatically executes npm install and npm start. So to build the static dependencies I use

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install -F && gulp build",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "NODE_ENV=test mocha server/test --recursive"
  }
```

Which isnt working fine due to error in gulp build, which is as follows

```
[12:03:22] Starting 'styles'...
{ [Error: spawn ENOENT: Missing the Sass executable. Please install and make available on your PATH.]
  message: 'spawn ENOENT: Missing the Sass executable. Please install and make available on your PATH.',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-ruby-sass',
  __safety: { toString: [Function] } }
[12:03:22] 'css' all files 0 B
```

So I did this

```
packages:
  rubygems:
     sass: ''
```

and placed the file in **.ebextensions/01config.config** but no change in error. Have tried doing numerous other things but ended up doing the following as my last idea

```
   "postinstall": "bower install -F && gulp build && sh postgulp.sh",
```

and creating a **postgulp.sh** file in the project root

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd
ls

if hash sass 2>/dev/null; then
    sass --update ./client/css:./public-debug/css --sourcemap=auto;
else
    echo >&2 "I require sass but it's not installed.  Continuing without sass.";
fi
```

Still no luck. Even though I have sass in rubygems dependency but its not in the PATH. Why? When are ebextensions scripts executed as opposed to npm install and postinstall? Why is some thing that is installed in ebextensions only available to those scripts and not to npm? Why dosent gulp-ruby-sass pick up sass?

Comment: Can you ssh to the instance to where sass dependency is installed? There can be two versions of ruby on the instance - one in /usr/bin and another one in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby.

Comment: yes, sass is installed in opt/elasticbeanstalk/ruby

Answer (score 0):

There can be two versions of ruby on the instance - one in /usr/bin and another one in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/lib/ruby.

Since you said SAAS is installed in the latter you need to make sure that the version of ruby on path when running your app is the same.

Most likely node is trying to use system ruby in /usr/bin and hence cannot find the gem.

Comment: I dont want to do it manually. What do I change in my ebextensions to make sure this happens in deploy cycle

Comment: Can you provide a sample application to repro the problem? I can then try fixing it using an ebextension

Comment: will try to do it tomorrow, with package.json and bower.json and some static files we should fine?